# Line starts next to node (not at it)

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

I want to connect two points, which are defined by nodes, by a (arrowed) line.
Here is my broken down code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
 \node (oe) at (0,0)[]{};
 \node (x) at (2,0)[]{};
 \draw[dashed, black] (oe) -- +(0,1) node[red](xstart){.};
 \draw[dashed, black] (x) -- +(0,1)  node[red](xend){.};
 \draw[<->,black] (xstart) -- (xend) node[above left]{$x$};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Which displays as:

[image: not working]

I can not figure out  why the line does not connect the two red dots.

Thanks for your help!

Solution (thanks to "js bibra", see below):
add option 'coordinate' to node

```
\draw[dashed, black] (oe) -- +(0,1) node[red, coordinate](xstart){.};
```

Comment: on account of the inner sep(arator) of the nodes in red color

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

```
    \draw[dashed, black] (oe) -- +(0,1) node[red, coordinate](xstart){.};
    \draw[dashed, black] (x) -- +(0,1)  node[red, coordinate](xend){.};
```

OR

changing the definition code to

```
    \draw[dashed, black] (oe) -- +(0,1) node[draw=none, coordinate,circle, fill=red, inner sep=4pt,](xstart){};
```

would give

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, js bibra! :)

Answer (score 2):

`nodes` has certain default size arround it's contents. Look at your code with `draw` option applied to the nodes:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
 \node[draw] (oe) at (0,0)[]{};
 \node[draw] (x) at (2,0)[]{};
 \draw[dashed, black] (oe) -- +(0,1) node[draw, red](xstart){.};
 \draw[dashed, black] (x) -- +(0,1)  node[draw, red](xend){.};
 \draw[<->,black] (xstart) -- (xend) node[above left]{$x$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

And lines between nodes stop at their (visible or invisible) border.

You can avoid this behaviour if drawn the line between node's centers:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
 \node[draw] (oe) at (0,0)[]{};
 \node[draw] (x) at (2,0)[]{};
 \draw[dashed, black] (oe) -- +(0,1) node[draw, red](xstart){.};
 \draw[dashed, black] (x) -- +(0,1)  node[draw, red](xend){.};
 \draw[<->,black] (xstart.center) -- (xend.center) node[above left]{$x$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

or replaces `nodes` by `coordinates` which are like nodes but without any dimension nor content.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \draw[dashed, black] (0,0) coordinate (oe) -- +(0,1) coordinate (xstart);
 \draw[dashed, black] (2,0) coordinate (x) -- +(0,1) coordinate (xend);
 \fill[red] (xstart) circle (1pt);
 \fill[red] (xend) circle (1pt);
 \draw[<->,black] (xstart.center) -- (xend.center) node[above left]{$x$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]